# hyperlinks are not working out side of carousel slide show on chrome

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

www.encyclopediasindhiana.org/index2.php

i have designed slide show from mycarousel with help of php, is working fine, but in frnt of carousel on left side the hyperlinks are not working till the height of carousel. on left side all links are not working if image is as large as the height covered by links...... you may try the third slide /image of carousel as its height is small so many hyperlinks came after its height are working.
why this is happening on chrome, while on internet explorer all links are working normally.

in bootstap.min.css file i have decleared width 539 and height auto,

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
display: block;
max-width: 539;
height: auto;}
```

In css in index2.php i decleared

```
 <style>
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

#myCarousel.carousel.slide {width: 100%; max-width: 539px; !important}
.carousel-caption {
 background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
 }



</style>
```

links are not working outeside carousel can java help if then how, plz i dont know much about java

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question, some hyper links are not clickable because of the container of the carousel are placed over the links which are not clickable. A quick solution is to remove the class name "container" from the closest block about the carousel. like use class="sd" instead class="container sd". 
Also please note that the class name "container" are the predefined class from bootstrap css which is need to be use for a proper area and with a proper structure.

For debug the issue use a html/css inspector tools like firebug etc, it will help you lot to learn about DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Using your browser's developer tools to inspect elements on the page, you will see there is a `<div class='container sd'>` extending to the left of your carousel, and overlapping your links - which stops them from working as the div gets the click events instead. Removing the `container` class 'fixes' the links with slight effects on the centering of your carousel.

[The relevant Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) specifically states that containers are not nestable, and since you are already using a `container-fluid` as the topmost element you will need to solve that centering issue some other way.